# PHP hierarchical array - To check if child value is there or not, then assign parent properties value assign to its child array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, nested-loops

We have below PHP hierarchical array

```
$arr = [
[
    'id' => 1,
    'parent_id' => 0,
    'access_type' => 'full-access',
    'child' => [
        [
            'id' => 4,
            'parent_id' => 1,
            'access_type' => '',
        ],
        [
            'id' => 5,
            'parent_id' => 1,
            'access_type' => '',
        ],
    ],
],
[
    'id' => 2,
    'parent_id' => 0,
    'access_type' => 'read',
    'child' => [
        [
            'id' => 10,
            'parent_id' => 2,
            'access_type' => 'read-write',
            'child' => [
                [
                    'id' => 11,
                    'parent_id' => 10,
                    'access_type' => '',
                ],
                [
                    'id' => 12,
                    'parent_id' => 10,
                    'access_type' => 'read',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        [
            'id' => 7,
            'parent_id' => 3,
            'access_type' => 'read-write',
        ],
    ],
],
[
    'id' => 3,
    'parent_id' => 0,
    'access_type' => 'full-access',
    'child' => [
        [
            'id' => 6,
            'parent_id' => 3,
            'access_type' => '',
            'child' => [
                [
                    'id' => 8,
                    'parent_id' => 6,
                    'access_type' => '',
                ],
                [
                    'id' => 9,
                    'parent_id' => 6,
                    'access_type' => '',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        [
            'id' => 18,
            'parent_id' => 3,
            'access_type' => '',
        ],
    ],
],
[
    'id' => 13,
    'parent_id' => 0,
    'access_type' => '',
    'child' => [
        [
            'id' => 14,
            'parent_id' => 13,
            'access_type' => 'full-access',
            'child' => [
                [
                    'id' => 15,
                    'parent_id' => 14,
                    'access_type' => '',
                ],
                [
                    'id' => 16,
                    'parent_id' => 14,
                    'access_type' => '',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        [
            'id' => 17,
            'parent_id' => 13,
            'access_type' => '',
        ],
    ],
],
];
```

We need output like this

[image]

We have here hierarchical array, I would like to display `access_type` is `full-access` if its nested child is blank.

We have tried the below code.

```
func_x($arr);

function func_x($arr, $level = 0)
{
    foreach($arr as $x)
    {
        echo str_repeat("---", $level) . " [" . $x['id'] . "] -> " . $x['access_type'] . "<br>";

        if(!empty($x['child']))
        {
            func_x($x['child'], $level+1);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Before proposing code, can you please confirm the value of [11] in the expected output? In the picture it is set to '', but if I get the logic right it should be 'read-write'.

Comment: @IvicaPesovski for the value of [11] I want blank, I want only `full-access` value change.

Comment: Why do you want 11 as blank but 6, 8 and 9 populated as full-access?

Comment: @ascsoftw If parents found `full-access` then the only child should have `full-access`.

Comment: @ChiragPipariya Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below code:

```
func_x($arr);

function func_x($arr, $level = 0, $parent = '')
{
    foreach($arr as $x)
    {
        if( empty ( $x['access_type'] ) && $parent == 'full-access' ) {
            $x['access_type'] = $parent;
        }
        echo str_repeat("---", $level) . " [" . $x['id'] . "] -> " . $x['access_type'] . "<br>";

        if(!empty($x['child']))
        {
            func_x($x['child'], $level+1, $x['access_type']);
        }
    } 
}
```

Basically you need to pass the parent access_type to your recursive function as third parameter.

Online Demo [here](https://3v4l.org/Vk5ZQ)

Comment: @ChiragPipariya Glad to Help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the parent access type to the function

```
func_x($arr);

function func_x($arr, $level = 0, $parentAccessType = '')
{
    foreach($arr as $x)
    {
        if($x['access_type'] == ''){
            $x['access_type'] = $parentAccessType;
        }
        echo str_repeat("---", $level) . " [" . $x['id'] . "] -> " . $x['access_type'] . "<br>";

        if(!empty($x['child']))
        {
            func_x($x['child'], $level+1, $x['access_type']);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: thanks, But we need the parents found `full-access` then the only child should have `full-access`.